# How can I correctly add a null item to JavaFX's ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx-8

How can I correctly add a `null` item to JavaFX's `ComboBox<T>`?

[image: ComboBox]

I have tried this:

```
@FXML 
private ComboBox<Producto> comboProductos;
private ObservableList<Producto> productos;

productos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ProductoDAO.obtenerProductos());
productos.add(0, null);
comboProductos.setItems(productos);
```

It works, but it throws this **Exception** when selecting the `null` item:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$177(ListViewBehavior.java:269) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:378) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1403) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:256) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:220) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
```

Comment: What is the code at the _line number_: MainApp.java: 273

Comment: I corrected it, it wasn't NullPointerException it is IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example code which adds a `null` to the `ComboBox`. The code runs without any runtime errors:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.collections.*;
public class FxComboBox extends Application {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                                new Product(1, "Books"),
                                                new Product(2, "Pencils"),
                                                new Product(3, "Folders"),
                                                new Product(9, "Paper Clips"));
        products.add(0, null);
        ComboBox<Product> productsCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        productsCombo.setItems(products);
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.getChildren().add(productsCombo);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Combo Box Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Product(int id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(id) + " " + name;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is a work around solution:
Create a `Product` called as a *dummy*. This will have an id=-1 (or something which is not used in real application) and the name="" (empty string). The `Product` class's overridden `toString` method may consider this *dummy* product and return an empty string:

```
public String toString() {
    if ((id == -1) && (name.isEmpty())) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return Integer.toString(id) + " " + name;
    }
}
```

And the example's code reflects this:

*Change this:*

```
products.add(0, null);
```

*to:*

```
Product dummy = new Product(-1, "");
products.add(0, dummy);
```

Comment: That's the same that I'm doing, and still throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Tell me what is the reason you want to use a _null_ product in the combobox ?

Comment: I have added a workaround solution to the answer. See the **Update**.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `ComboBoxItem<T>`-class that contains an Element of type `Producto`.
That way you can set the contained element to null but still return a String in the `toString()`-Method.
The Combox would then contain ComboxItems instead of Products.

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution that works with any custom object you want to use.

First create this class called GenericCallback:

```
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public abstract class GenericCallback<T> implements Callback<ListView<Object>, ListCell<Object>> {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Object> call(ListView<Object> param) {
        final ListCell<Object> cell = new ListCell<Object>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Object t, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(t, empty);
                try {
                    if (t instanceof String) {
                        setText((String)t);
                    } else {
                        //hopefully it is generic
                        T abc = (T)t;
                        setText(toText(abc));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //oh well, looks like it was not.
                    setText("");
                }
        };
        return cell;
    }

    public abstract String toText(T object);
}
```

Then you implement it like this:

```
GenericCallback gc = new GenericCallback<User>() {
    @Override
    public String toText(User user) {
        return FormattingUtil.getUserName(user);
    }
};
ComboBox comboboxUser = new Combobox();
comboboxUser.setButtonCell(gc.call(null));
comboboxUser.setCellFactory(gc);
comboboxUser.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Object selectedItem = comboboxIzd.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedItem instanceof User) {
            User thisUserIsSelected = (User) selectedItem;
            //do whatever you wish with it
        } else {
            //empty item was selected - no user was selected, do whatever you wish with it
        }
    }
});
```

And this is how you can populate your combobox with strings or objects:

```
comboboxUser.getItems().add("");//add empty string for example
comboboxIzd.getItems().add("no selection but still some text");
comboboxUser.getItems().addAll(listOfSomeUserObjects);
comboboxIzd.getItems().add("no selection at the end ...");
```

No runtime error since you do not add null object to combobox. With new combobox you just replace generic type User and you handle another object. I hope it helps.